# ORA-00904: "PSTATUSTYPE": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 67 Column: 11

Tags: oracle, case, identifier, ora-00904

When I try to run the below SQL:

```
SELECT  
p_mv.created_by                            createby, 
from  pipeline             p_mv, 
pipeline             p_con, 

route route_s , 

 where  
    "pstatustype"='CTA'
     and
    case when pstatustype='CTA' then p_con.created_date
           when pstatustype='VAD' then route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date
           when pstatustype='ETA' then route_s.arrival_date
           else null -- default anyway
      end Between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
              AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS');
```

I am getting an error for psstatustype column:

> ORA-00904: "**PSTATUSTYPE**": invalid identifier
>     00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>      *Cause:
>   *Action:     Error at Line: 67 Column: 11

`psstatustype` is not present at the DB end. I'm creating this on the fly for the case distribution under where clause. Please help!!

Regards,
    fuko

Comment: Your CASE statement must consist of tests on something valid. You must be pulling the values of `pstatustype` from somewhere. Is it meant to be a parameter?

Comment: yes, you are right. it's a parameter.I have to enter it's value at the runtime with fromdate and todate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "it's a parameter."

Your posted SQL is mangled so this is **not** a working example (for instance you have a cross join with no join conditions so it will return a Cartesian product). Anyway it shows you the sort of thing you need to do:

```
SELECT  
     ....
from  pipeline             p_mv, 
      pipeline             p_con, 
      route route_s , 
 where  
    case '&pstatustype'
           when 'CTA' then p_con.created_date
           when 'VAD' then route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date
           when 'ETA' then route_s.arrival_date
           else null -- default anyway
      end 
      between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
              AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS');
```

This uses the SQL*Plus substitution variable syntax `&pstatustype` which will prompt you to enter a value each time you run the query. Different clients may demand a different way of specifying and populating parameters.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help.I really appreciate it. This is the first time I'm closely interacting with the SQL code and people on stackoverflow are awesome and very helpful. I'm learning alot from you.. people like you,  are the reason for the popularity of this website. One more time Thank you so much for your help!! fuko